# Pattern Match Using SED or GREP

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I need to extract a part of a string.
The strings are as below,

`/ba/mn/first one
/ba/mn/second
/ba/mn/third`

and so on.

There are hundreds of such strings. I need to extract the below parts from the strings,
first one
second
third
and so on

Please help me out in doing this as i am new to world of pattern matching and i am learning it.

Thanks,
Sunil.

THe code i used is ,
`grep s/^.*branches/`

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` one-liner:

```
while read line; do basename "$line"; done<yourfile
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's#^\(.*\)/\([^/]*\)$#\2#p' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `basename` and `xargs`: `xargs -a yourfile -n1 basename`